What properties on boundary conditions for a second-order PDE to have a unique solution?
Suppose I have a PDE on a complex-valued function $f(\vec x)$ for some set of variables $\vec x\in \mathbb R^n$, where the domain of $f$ is $D\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and suppose the PDE is some linear combination of first- or second-order partial derivates of $f$ w.r.t. some variables in $\vec x$.
I know some specific boundary conditions I could specify in some specific cases that would give a unique solution. E.g. if $f(t,x,y,z)$ and the PDE is $\partial_t f=\nabla^2 f$, then a possible boundary condition is $f(T,x,y,z)=g(x,y,z)$ for a smooth $g$ and some specific $T$.
But what are the general conditions that my boundary conditions need to satisfy to ensure that a unique solution exists? If we don't have such general conditions, could you give a "map" of which PDEs we understand (meaning we have assumptions on boundary conditions together with an existence and uniqueness proof).

Have a look at hyperbolic, elliptic, and parabolic to start.

Usually Dirichlet ($f(t, \cdot)\vert_{\partial D}=0$) is such a condition. I have rarely seen $f(T, x, y, z) = ...$. Usually, these conditions are set at $T=0$.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend, could you specify what $f(t,\cdot)|_{\partial D}$ means? In particular, the $|\partial D$ part.

$\vert_{\partial D}$ means "on the boundary of $D$". What I mean is that $f(t, x) =0$ for every $(t, x) \in (0, T) \times \partial D$

There are simply too many exotic PDEs to give a "general" boundary condition that guarantees existince of a solution. We can only restrict ourselves to special cases such as first order, second order, linear, parabolic, hyperbolic, elliptic, conservative, etc etc....
